# Stored procedure doesn't return correct value

Tags: sql-server

I have stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ReplaceHtmlEntities
    @companyName  NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @newCompanyName NVARCHAR(200);

    SET @newCompanyName = @companyName;
    SET @newCompanyName = REPLACE(@newCompanyName,'&amp;','&');
    SET @newCompanyName = REPLACE(@newCompanyName,'&quot;','"');
    SET @newCompanyName = REPLACE(@newCompanyName,'&#039;','''');
    SELECT @newCompanyName;
END
GO
```

But it returns 0:

```
DECLARE @companyName nvarchar(200), @result nvarchar(200)

SET @companyName = N'Company name &amp;'

EXEC    @result = [dbo].[ReplaceHtmlEntities] @companyName

SELECT  @result
```

@result should be 'Company name &' but it gives me '0' - why ?

Comment: Stored Procedures generate and send back to the calling client two things: 1) an integer error code as a "Return value" ; and 2) one or multiple tabular result sets (the things specified by Select statements in the SP)
You are looking at the first one the integer return value, which (if there was no error), is zero by default

Comment: But I must use @result in my query in SELECT - how can I do that ?

Comment: But this functionality would be better as a User defined function (UDF) not as a stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedure can only return integers ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)).

You could return it from an output parameter, but I think you should create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReplaceHtmlEntities
    (@companyName  NVARCHAR(200))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @newCompanyName NVARCHAR(200);

    SET @newCompanyName = @companyName;
    SET @newCompanyName = REPLACE(@newCompanyName,'&amp;','&');
    SET @newCompanyName = REPLACE(@newCompanyName,'&quot;','"');
    SET @newCompanyName = REPLACE(@newCompanyName,'&#039;','''');

    RETURN @newCompanyName;
END
GO
```

And this is how you can execute a function:

```
DECLARE @companyName nvarchar(200), @result nvarchar(200)
SET @companyName = N'Company name &amp;'

SET @result = [dbo].[ReplaceHtmlEntities](@companyName)

SELECT  @result
```

Comment: but make it an inline UDF, not a procedural one.

Answer (score 1):

Where you call it, eliminate the `@result =` and the line `select @result`.

The select *inside* the SP will generate the data for you.

```
DECLARE @companyName nvarchar(200), @result nvarchar(200)
SET @companyName = N'Company name &amp;'
EXEC [dbo].[ReplaceHtmlEntities] @companyName
```

But if you made it a UDF it would be better,,,

```
 Create Function dbo.ReplaceHtmlEntities(@input varChar(1000) )
 returns table As
 Return (Select Replace(Replace(REPLACE(
                @input,'&amp;','&'), 
                       '&quot;','"'),
                       '&#039;','''') OutVal)
```

Then all you need to do to call it is

```
Select OutVal from dbo.ReplaceHtmlEntities('Put the companyname here')
```

Comment: This would be a great answer if the syntax was correct.

Comment: yes, I normally use the template and did not have access when I answered this

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures in SQL Server can only return integers. The SELECT at the end of the stored procedure is going to create a result set not a return value.

To output the value form a stored procedure as a Output Parameter declare the procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ReplaceHtmlEntities
    @companyName  NVARCHAR(200),
    @newCompanyName NVARCHAR(200) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @newCompanyName = @companyName;
    SET @newCompanyName = REPLACE(@newCompanyName,'&amp;','&');
    SET @newCompanyName = REPLACE(@newCompanyName,'&quot;','"');
    SET @newCompanyName = REPLACE(@newCompanyName,'&#039;','''');
END
GO

DECLARE @companyName nvarchar(200) = 'A &amp; B'

EXEC ReplaceHtmlEntities @companyName = @companyName, @newCompanyName = @companyName OUTPUT

SELECT  @companyName

GO
```

Comment: Thanks. Not any more.